# Calculating Orwin's (1983) modified Fail-safe N in a meta-analysis with Odds Ratio as summary statistic?

Tags: meta-analysis, cohens-d, odds-ratio

I am attempting to calculate Orwin's (1983) modification of Rosenthal's (1979) Fail-safe N for my meta-analysis of Odds Ratios.

However, all the equations I am finding are using Cohen's d, which I cannot calculate (I don't have two groups).

I have STATA, SPSS, and MedCalc at my disposal.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you always find ways to convert effect size. For example you can calculate $r$ from $d$ and back. So you surely will be able to converts odds ratio to Cohen's $d$.
One book I usually found a good resource for stuff like that is the one by Rosenthal & Rosnow. I think it was this one:
[Rosenthal & Rosnow - Essentials of Behavioral Research: Methods and Data Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073531960)

But in your case you should take a look at his paper, it will probably solve your problem (but I haven't looked at it):
[Chinn, S. (2000). A simple method for converting an odds ratio to effect size for use in meta-analysis. Statistic in Medicine, 19, 3127-3131.](http://www.citeulike.org/group/3472/article/2833123)

Comment: +1 Great link, I missed this reference -- so I guess now it can be handled within R without any problem :) I put the PDF at this address in case someone want to read it: http://j.mp/bnnwsu

Answer (score 1):

So, perhaps check these additional resources: http://j.mp/d8znoP for SPSS. Don't know about Stata.
There is some R code about fail-safe N in the following handout: [Tests for funnel plot asymmetry and failsafe N](http://www.biostat.uzh.ch/teaching/phd/doktorandenseminar/schroedle.pdf), but I didn't check on the [www.metaanalysis.com](http://www.metaanalysis.com) website.

Otherwise, [ClinTools Software](http://www.clintools.com/) may be an option (I hope the demo version let you do some computation on real data), or better the [MIX](http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2288/6/50) software.